# Binding behavior to dynamic object differs between WPF and WinRT

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net, winrt-xaml, expandoobject

I am trying to data bind a Xaml property to a property of a dynamic object. In this case the dynamic object is a `JObject` from the [Json.Net library](http://james.newtonking.com/json). `JObject` is a well behaved dynamic object and I've had no problems with it in the past. It makes for a lightweight way to go to/from json serialized objects and C# code.

In this case however the binding throws an exception at runtime.

The binding:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserProfile.Value.name}"/>
```

where `Value` is a `JObject` and `name` a dynamic property (string)

The exception:

```
    Error: BindingExpression path error: 'name' property not found on 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, 
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. 
BindingExpression: Path='UserProfile.Value.name' DataItem='Google.Apps.ViewModel.MainViewModel'; 
target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' 
(type 'String')
```

Curiously if I explicitly convert the JObject to an ExpandoObject the binding works.

```
private dynamic _value; // set to a deserialized JObject elsewhere
public dynamic Value
{
    get
    {
        if (_value != null) // debug code
        {
            dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
            o.name = _value.name;
            return o;
        }
        return _value;
    }
}
```

For binding to dynamic objects to work does the data object need to be an `ExpandoObject`. Obviously the binding is interrogating the dataobject's type and using reflection to get the property and value. Is there special case logic for `ExpandoObject` and is `ExpandoObject` the only option for doing this?

**UPDATE**

As @dkozl points out this type of binding works with straight up WPF. I can get the desired behavior with this WPF window and dynamic property:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="root"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock FontSize="36" Width="920">Label</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheName.name, ElementName=root}" FontSize="36"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public dynamic TheName
    {
        get
        {
            string json = @"{ 'name': 'James' }";
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

However with a WinRT 8.1 Store app this very similar binding produces an error:

```
<Page
    x:Name="root"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock FontSize="36" >Label</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheName.name, ElementName=root}" FontSize="36"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public dynamic TheName
    {
        get
        {
            string json = @"{ 'name': 'James' }";
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple project that demonstrates this is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE5497473B4CE9CD!13652&authkey=!AFfbSRNG7HI4Gjs&ithint=file,.zip). Unfortunately it looks like a difference of behavior in WinRT binding.

Comment: I've just tried simplest binding to `JObject` where context is set like `DataContext = JObject.Parse(@"{ 'name': 'James' }");` and it seems to work. I've also tried with `Value` property, just like yours, and it works without `ExpandoObject` convertion

Comment: weird. The object in question is generated by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json). I'll play around with it a bit see if I can figure anything else out

Comment: It also works if instead of `JObject.Parse(...)` I do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(...)`. Maybe try it on a clean project and see at which point it breaks

Comment: Fresh project with no extraneous bits same binding error. This is a .net 4.5, WinRt 8.1 universal app building in vs.net 2013. Are you seeing success in straight up WPF?

Comment: Simple Windows WPF app, .NET4, VS2013 and can't remember what version of Json.NET but latest installed from Nuget

Comment: Simple reproducing project here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE5497473B4CE9CD!13652&authkey=!AFfbSRNG7HI4Gjs&ithint=file%2c.zip